# How to simultaniously search for two possible quotation marks with regular expressions?

Tags: python, regex, quotation-marks

I want to extract words in quotation marks if they are one or two words long. This works with the following Code.

```py
mysentences = ['Kids, you "tried" your "best" and you failed miserably. The "lesson" is, "never try."', 
               "Just because I don’t 'care' doesn’t mean I don’t understand."]
quotation = []
rx = r'"((?:\w+[ .]*){1,2})"' 
for sentence in mysentences:
    quotation.append(re.findall(rx, sentence))
print(quotation)
```

But this doesn't get me the 'care' from the sencond sentence because the second sentence is in double quotation marks. I can get it with the following

```py
r"'((?:\w+[ .]*){1,2})'"
```

The Question is, how can I join the conditions? with

```py
rx = r'"((?:\w+[ .]*){1,2})"' or r"'((?:\w+[ .]*){1,2})'"
```

it only gets me the first mentioned condition.

Comment: [`"|'`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your current pattern, you could make use of a [capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) and a backreference `\1` to match the accompanying single or double quote.

The match will now be in the second capturing group.

```
(['"])((?:\w+[ .]*){1,2})\1
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kBOVDp/1)

Note that repeating the character class `[ .]*` could potentially also match for example`never try... ....`

If you want to match 1 or 2 words where there can be a single optional dot at the end, you could match 1+ word chars followed by an optional group to match 1+ spaces and 1+ word chars followed by an optional dot.

```
(['"])(\w+(?: +\w+)?\.?)\1
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4SKiLv/1)

For example

```
import re
mysentences = ['Kids, you "tried" your "best" and you failed miserably. The "lesson" is, "never try."',
               "Just because I don’t 'care' doesn’t mean I don’t understand."]
quotation = []
rx = r"(['\"])((?:\w+[ .]*){1,2})\1"
for sentence in mysentences:
    for m in  re.findall(rx, sentence):
        quotation.append(m[1])

print(quotation)
```

Result

```
['tried', 'best', 'lesson', 'never try.', 'care']
```

Comment: Unfortunately this also gives me the Quotation mark itself. I get  [[('"', 'tried'), ('"', 'best'), ('"', 'lesson'), ('"', 'never try.')], [("'", 'care')]]

Comment: @maybeyourneighour The matches are in the second capturing group. See for example https://ideone.com/Orekun

Comment: @maybeyourneighour I have added an example to the answer getting the second value from the tuple that re.findall returns.

Comment: Great! It works. But now I get one list for all sentences instead of one list for each sentence.

Comment: @maybeyourneighour I see, do you mean like this? https://ideone.com/Ujmqxq

Comment: Exactly! Thank you for your help